# compilation error due to a header file which is available in a shared library while using g++

Tags: linker, g++, shared-libraries

I have a */usr/lib/libtiff.so.3* as a symbolic link to */usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.3*.  I need to use some data structures declared in a file called *tiffio.h* which is part of the tiff library mentioned above to handle .tif image files in my c++ source. The c++ source *mycode.cpp* is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tiffio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

if (argc < 2) {
    cout << "USAGE: mycode <inputimage> <outputimage> "<< endl;
    return (-1);
}
 return 0;
}
```

I compile the source with g++ in the following way:

```
g++ -Wall -L/usr/lib mycode.cpp -ltiff -o mycode
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal error: tiffio: No such file or directory. compilation terminated.
```

I have tried with using the following options for including the *tiffio.h* but error persists.

```
<tiffio>, "tiffio.h",  extern "C" {"tiffio.h"} and extern "C" {<tiffio.h>}
```

Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong? How can I compile and link the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where your tiffio.h file is.
If it is at a place where your g++ usually looks for header files you can include it using

```
#include <tiffio.h>
```

If it is in the same directory as your .cpp File you can include it using

```
#include "tiffio.h"
```

If it is somewhere else you have two possibilities:

Either add its location to your search path by adding -I pathToLocation to your g++ call

Or include it using

```
#include "pathToLocation/tiffio.h"
```

The directorys normaly searched by the g++ are

```
/usr/local/include
libdir/gcc/target/version/include
/usr/target/include
/usr/include
```

If the g++ can't find the library itself (the .so file) you can add it (with path) directly to your g++ call.

Comment: it is a part of the shared library libtiff.so

Comment: But do you know where it is? Meaning its path, eg. /usr/include/tiffio.h

Comment: He's referring to the header file itself. Often times, the header isn't located with the shared library, especially if you've never installed the headers with the library. What distro/environment are you using? Redhat, Ubuntu, Mingw?

Comment: @Jason Huntley: I am on ubuntu 11.04

Comment: @Haatschii: I get the problem now. I always thought that the shared library has the header file. Sorry I missed this point.